# I cannot install mysql-connector-python using pip

Tags: pip, pypi, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to install `mysql-connector-python==1.0.12` as part of my project's automated installation, and I get the following error from `pip install`:

```
Collecting mysql-connector-python==1.0.12 (from -r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 20))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python==1.0.12 (from -r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 20)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python==1.0.12 (from -r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 20))
```

Up until a few days ago it worked fine. I investigated a bit and found the following [issue in bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issues/365/many-packages-have-empty-list-of-links). Specifically, the following comment dated 28/12/2015:

> That should be blank, per PEP 470 using PyPI to link to a package not
>   hosted by PyPI for automated installers to download (the /simple/
>   index) was deprecated and scheduled for removal. Maintainers of the
>   affected packages were emailed 3 months ago. The removal happened
>   earlier today (a bug caused some oackages like Twisted which were
>   hosted on PyPI to also have their links removed but that has been
>   remedied). The maintainers of MySQL-connector-python should either
>   upload to PyPI or direct their users to use either -f or
>   --extra-index-url with a repository they maintain.

How can I have the installation of `mysql-connector-python==1.0.12` run smoothly?
Do I need to set up my own repository?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are quite a few solutions, e.g. hosting a private repository, but the quickest was to change the `requirements.txt` file to download from mysql's cdn.

i.e., to change:

```
mysql-connector-python==1.0.12
```

to

```
https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.15.tar.gz
```

Comment: @Ammon can you update your answer with https download link? https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-1.0.12.tar.gz

 https is better option because of security reasons

Comment: https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz  - Version 2.1.3 is now available edit to select latest version

Comment: I found I needed to do `pip install --egg http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.4.zip` to get the latest version to work.

Answer (score 29):

For all the lazy people like me who had to google how the requirements file works

**just do this ...**

```
echo https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz >> requirements.txt
```

then this.

```
sudo -H pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

check it.

```
pip list | grep mysql
```

It should output:

```
mysql-connector-python (2.1.3)
```

happy days Thanks to @Amnon

Comment: Please update the cdn link if there is one. Else the below answer seems to work better: pip install mysql-connector-python-rf

Answer (score 16):

Worked for me using 

    `pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`.

More info here https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5369

Answer (score 5):

The above link did not work for me, or when trying to install to AWS Beanstalk. But the below link did work:

```
https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.0.4.zip#md5=3df394d89300db95163f17c843ef49df
```

Answer (score 3):

## Red Hat / CentOS

```
sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel
sudo pip3 install mysql-connector
```

for other OS, see [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1):

For **requirements.txt**
`mysql-connector-python~=8.0.5`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `setup.py` script, keep the dependency listed in `install_requies` but add the attribute `depedency_links` to the setup function with a list and put the url to the package in there. Such as:

```
setup(
    dependency_links=['http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.4.zip']
)
```

More is specified in the [Packages Not On PyPI](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html#packages-not-on-pypi) document.