# Configure .travis.yml to support mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, mysql, pip, travis-ci

I am using python 2.7.11 on TravisCI and I want to configure TravisCI to work properly. But travis CI fails on

```
import mysql.connector
```

I have tried adding

```
pip install mysql-connector-python==2.1.3 --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

to my .travis.yml. However, travisCI report that

```
--allow-external
```

is deprecated and has no effect. If I remove it the

```
--allow-external
```

it still fails. Also no matter what version I change it to it also will never install the mysql-connector-python.

Does anyone know how I configure my .travis.yml to get TravisCI to work with mysql.connector?

Here is full file:

```
language: python
python:
- 2.7.11
install: pip install pymongo Flask flask-cors tornado coverage codeclimate-test-reporter ddt mysql-connector-python==2.1.3
script: 
- python -m unittest discover tests
notifications:
  slack:
    secure: 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
addons:
  code_climate:
    repo_token:
      secure: h19Nm48/J3+BGrfiG90hgmUaA/oiIYxTpFutQYB8Dm7SV9RHW02ypvpS8B81Ne4WxHZE1DmrO1KUqEQ3j2IH27gjidwci32Wjuv7C8ikOzQ/F0lFt0ydkKQH1NZJQCqQJOYnJSiM95fRKQOWgK0pM2et/5m3Pr9fXnffKYaE2Yhv+zKbcy0wmCiT8n1aMgxs714KcMAcqR1kptEid122ORssawzfkJBewM6Z6RXlUq8EeU86UIllk5eBPMCUso7BSEWl6jptjeyWGo/6/NkE06+XBSkvM5VEdAAA0rUh3n41SZVWo0SegFmE+HZegjE6w76XWcTrbVLZNTSN1jqdZTaPhq+9TB0OqGJp28bziYkVxY9Z2Yd0OacyGlGmdBwkrIEtmA0Wjiubbx96P95m3AEwYJlyYWxUGV8HSJFn1pH9KMb6Ewc+/rCeA5o4f8+r098aqtnNNzxpWaxAn0Up//GVPlH74SiyfHMrd/+uTFC9TCtAazHq4GLiJrESoVaapXTY9XabIGE205NxfQ6PIRPfsFjK0cH5BR0ZkJt5EspEHc7HgAIn0kotuJYgAJ64hcfOimeSTDBSBn138TDJTscTjpZrOl0LYXChhcuTH2MOx2nS/4miKHteFW8mOSuoVaunQHt9+8HDlRrD8n48lm/qYkh8jG1UnPBW7iqKxtI=
```

Comment: Could you post your entire `.travis.yml`?

Comment: Or more `.travis.yml` context? I'd there a `install: ` prefix on the line you posted?

Comment: Also, have you tried using a `requirements.txt` as mentioned at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python#Dependency-Management? Can that work for your use case?

Comment: ...just added  full .travis.yml file to question...I'm not sure how simply putting the mysql-connector-python would make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like 2.1.2 may not be hosted at PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python only shows 2.0.4 and a 1.x.

[I cannot install mysql-connector-python using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489271/i-cannot-install-mysql-connector-python-using-pip) leads me to believe that the package maintainer may not be publishing to PyPI correctly.

Try replacing the package name with a known working package download URL? E.g. https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.2.tar.gz? (Latest is 2.1.3 as of time of writing - probably also available via CDN.)

Alternatively, try downgrading to 2.0.4 - it *is* on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/2.0.4.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized I could use a URL with pip install...here is the line in my .travis.yml updated. This works:    install: pip install pymongo Flask flask-cors tornado coverage codeclimate-test-reporter ddt https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.2.tar.gz

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for confirming the fix worked - should help future Travis CI Pythonistas!