# Importing mysql.connector into Azure Flask Project

Tags: python, azure, mysql-connector-python

I'm trying to deploy a Flask web app with mysql connectivity. It's my first time using Azure, and coming off Linux it all seems pretty confusing.

My understanding is that one includes within the `requirements.txt` to include the packages required. When I build the default Flask app from Azure the file looks like this:

`Flask<1`

At this stage the site loads fine.

If I then include an additional line
`https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.14.tar.gz`
As per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489738/2697874

Then in my views.py file (which seems to be broadly synonymous to my old app.py file) I include...`import mysql.connector`

I then restart and reload my site...which then returns the error `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

Error logging spits out a load of html (seems pretty weird way to deliver error logs - so I must be missing something here). When I save to html and load it up I get this...

[image]

**How can I include the mysql.connector library within my Flask web app?**

Comment: Why do you want to use that specific version, rather than just including `mysql-connector-python` directly in requirements.txt?

Comment: And note that using requirements.txt has nothing to do with Azure vs "Linux". It's good practice on *any* platform.

Comment: I don't have any preference for that specific version. I tried with `mysql-connector-python` too - same result

Comment: use this article to enable logging and get back to us with the error. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/07/14/troubleshoot-logging-python-application-errors-on-azure-webapi-apps/

Comment: Awesome - got some decent logging set up. The error is `File ".\FlaskWebProject1\views.py", line 8, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, the resoure `https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.14.tar.gz` is for Linux, not for Azure WebApps based on Windows, and the link seems to be not available now.

I used the command `pip search mysql-connector` to list the related package. Then, I tried to use `mysql-connector` instead of `mysql-connector-python` via `pip install`, and tried to `import mysql.connector` in local Python interpreter that works fine.

So please use `mysql-connector==2.1.4` instead of `mysql-connector-python==` in the `requirements.txt` file of your project using IDE, then **re-deploy** the project on Azure and try again. The package will be installed automatically as the offical [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-configure#package-management) said as below.

> Package Management 
>   Packages listed in requirements.txt will be installed automatically in the virtual environment using pip. **This happens on every deployment**, but pip will skip installation if a package is already installed.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Yes - this works. I had not understood the significance of redeploying vs restarting.