# Cant pip install from freeze

Tags: python, pip

I have just installed a bunch of packages to use MySQL on python, but I'm not sure which one did the trick (whichever it was,  only worked after a reboot).

Now I'm trying to use it on a virtualenv, so I created a requirements.txt with pip freeze on my local machine, then, I created a virtualenv and tried `pip install -r requirements.txt`. However, can't install any of the packages, and the error is:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python<=2.0.4 (from -r myvi/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python<=2.0.4 (from -r myvi/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Tried editing the file manually, but whatever the first line is, always report the same error.

Googling the subject, I've only found solutions that are particular to the packages, but I get errors for regardless of the package. Why is this happening?

EDIT: I thought that all the packages were raising error, but only some of them are. Namely:

```
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
Pyste==0.9.10
unity-lens-photos==1.0
```

I thought that if it was built by `pip freeze` , it would be possible to `pip install` it.

Comment: can you show us the content of your requirements file? (just a few lines)

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489271/i-cannot-install-mysql-connector-python-using-pip

Comment: `adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
cycler==0.10.0
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4`
(...)

Comment: Can you `pip install` anything? If the answer is no, I think its either a proxy problem (if you need a proxy) or a SSL certificate problem. Discussed here: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/41253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you installed `mysql-connector-python` before, but [its PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/) doesn't list any downloadable files for any of its versions, so you can't install it with pip (at least, not with a plain `pip install mysql-connector-python==2.0.4` or the like).  Try just deleting the `mysql-connector-python` line from your `requirements.txt` file.

The other packages you've mentioned (`adium-theme-ubuntu`, `Pyste`, and `unity-lens-photos`) don't even exist on PyPI, so `pip install` definitely won't work for them.

Comment: Not all packages from pip freeze can be installed by pip instal, that one included, thus, the error. Add that to your answer and I'll accept it.